# R calculate confidence interval for mean in aggregate, by function

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate, confidence-interval, group

I am intended to create a script that can generate a statistical information, grouped based on category (which in the example below; SDP & M346). I need the n, mean, standard deviation (sd), standard error (se) and confidence interval. I have the code ready for all except the confidence interval. I could not manage to embed the calculation of the confidence interval in group using `aggregate` function.

tab.sep.file

[image]

I was trying to print the mean/sd/se/confidence interval grouped by the column `SDP` and `M346`.

```
aggregate(tab.sep.file$Hic8, FUN=mean, by=list(SDP=tab.sep.file$SDP, trait=tab.sep.file$M346))
```

By switching the function to length, standard deviation and creating formula for standard error, I managed to obtain the statistics for grouped data in one go.
The output for the script above is something as below:
[image]

To calculate the confidence interval for the entire data (not grouping):

```
mean <- mean(tab.sep.file$Hic8)
n <- length(tab.sep.file$Hic8)
standard_deviation <- sd(tab.sep.file$Hic8)
standard_error <- standard_deviation / sqrt(n)
alpha = 0.05
degrees_of_freedom = n - 1
t_score = qt(p=alpha/2, df=degrees_of_freedom, lower.tail=F)
margin_error <- t_score * standard_error
 
# Calculating lower bound and upper bound
lower_bound <- mean_value - margin_error
upper_bound <- mean_value + margin_error
 
# Print the confidence interval
print(c(lower_bound,upper_bound))

embedded from [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-confidence-intervals-in-r/][3]
```

But how should I calculate the confidence interval based on the grouped data using the `aggregate` function in one go like the rest?

My main problem here is that instead of having one `n`, in grouped data, there will definitely having more than one `n`.

I have tried using `dplyr` tool too, but the output is incorrect, something seemed off.

```
> tab.sep.file %>%
+ group_by(SDP,M346) %>%
+ summarise(mean = mean(tab.sep.file$Hic8),
+ sd = sd(tab.sep.file$Hic8),
+ n = n()) %>%
+ mutate(se = sd / sqrt(n),
+ lower.ci = mean - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2 ), n -1) * se,
+ upper.ci = mean + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2 ), n -1) * se)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify grouping in `aggregate`. e.g. via formula. Try this

```
> aggf <- \(x) {
+   n <- length(x)
+   xmn <- mean(x)
+   xsd <- sd(x)
+   se <- xsd/sqrt(n)
+   ci <- xmn + se*(-qt(p=.05/2, df=n - 1)) %*% cbind(-1, 1)
+   c(mean=xmn, sd=xsd, se=se, ci=ci)
+ }
> aggregate(Hic8 ~ sdp, dat, aggf)
   sdp   Hic8.mean     Hic8.sd     Hic8.se    Hic8.ci1    Hic8.ci2
1 SDP1  0.64358665  0.20498872  0.08368630  0.42846418  0.85870913
2 SDP2  0.32132755  0.16655345  0.09615968 -0.09241416  0.73506925
3 SDP3  0.46302347  0.37685995  0.21758019 -0.47314854  1.39919549
```

---

*Data*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(sdp = c("SDP1", "SDP1", "SDP1", "SDP2", "SDP2", 
"SDP2", "SDP1", "SDP1", "SDP1", "SDP3", "SDP3", "SDP3"), Hic8 = c(0.854164426913485, 
0.382015778450295, 0.799342160811648, 0.144684031140059, 0.475511683383957, 
0.343786930665374, 0.629821318900213, 0.412683063885197, 0.783493172377348, 
0.534960983321071, 0.798729537520558, 0.0553799034096301)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```